# How would I change MongoDB active database based on a req.param?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a localized maintenance database that will be running on a LAN without internet access. I recently migrated from a SQL database to Mongo based on other requirements i need to meet moving forward and i'm attempting to get my existing functionality back up with the new express/mongo backend rather than the nginx/mariaDB i had been running. Once i get this back up i can move forward with adding the new requirements...

My issue right now is attempting to change the active database in MongoDB (using mongoose) based on a req.param. I can use the params in the actual queries but would like to have a database set for each of the high level hardware sets that need the app.

Example:

http://1.2.3.4/api/HardwareA/tasks to return items from the tasks collection of Hardware A database

http://1.2.3.4/api/HardwareB/tasks to return items from the tasks collection of Hardware B database

I have been trying to play with the useDB() functionality but have been unable to get anything working as stated above. I can get the paths working find by hardcoding the database into mongoose.connection but it's not very dynamic that way.

have the below across a couple different files working fien with hard coded databases and just need to try to figure out how to implement the database change at an early level.

I have the merge params in there because i tried to do the below with req.param.db for loading the databases but on initial build i always get req not defined, which makes sense to me. Just not sure how to go about doing this appropriately. All this express stuff is new to me. I'm certain it's something i am just not seeing.

Thanks for any assistance.

from package.json for version references.

```
"express": "^4.16.4",
"express-session": "^1.16.1",
"mongodb": "^3.2.3",
"mongoose": "^5.5.3",
```

api/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

const mongoUser = 'User'
const mongoPass = 'superPass'
const mongoServer = '192.168.5.5'
const mongoPort = '27017'
/* const mongoDB = req.param.db || ''
const mongoURI = `mongodb://${mongoUser}:${mongoPass}@${mongoServer}:${mongoPort}/maintCenter${mongoDB}?authSource=admin` // fail A */

const mongoURI = `mongodb://${mongoUser}:${mongoPass}@${mongoServer}:${mongoPort}/maintCenter?authSource=admin`

mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true
})

// mount the router on the app
app.options('*', cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/api', require('./routes'))

module.exports = app
```

api/routes/index.js *edit - added this file

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

router.use('/:db/taskdata', require('./taskRoute'))

module.exports = router
```

api/routes/taskRoute.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const taskRoute = express.Router({ mergeParams: true })

const Task = require('../models/taskModel')

// get all tasks
taskRoute.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
//gives mongoose.connection.useDB is not a function // Fail B
//mongoose.connection.useDB(`maintCenter${req.param.db}`)
  Task.find(function(err, tasks) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err)
    } else {
      res.json(tasks)
    }
  })
})

module.exports = taskRoute
```

questions:

**End Users**: about 30 guys across 3 or 4 work sites in my group. Most not technical at all.

**Platform**: VueJS web app, axios for submissions.

**Single Database**: Considered doing it as a multitenant using [This Library](https://github.com/craftup/node-mongo-tenant) but i got held up thinking about how to handle hardware specific backup/restore. There might be an easy way to handle and i just couldn't find it and that brought me back around to individual databases as i had with MariaDB. Not sold on either, was just reverting to what i had and knew.

On this topic, would i just be doing two finds for each command? it would be something like

```
Task.find(
  {
    hardware: 'A',
    somethingElse: '123'
  }
)
```

would it be possible to do something more along the line of

```
tasks = Task.find(hardware: 'A')

taskRoute.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
  Task.find(function(err, tasks) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err)
    } else {
      res.json(tasks)
    }
  })
})
```

I don't even know if that's reasonable. Just trying to figure out the best overall way to get it accomplished. Thanks very much for you assistance in reality checking me on this stuff. I have been reading for 2 weeks and got some skeleton code working a few days ago but this has been the longest hold up thus far. I hope the above fills in the right bits of data.

Comment: Make a Middleware to server this and try to make it from the header, not from the params.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer but I'm not satisfied with it. Will you need to have differents models on each database ? The biggest problem is that you can't just "change the active database", as models are linked to a database through the mongoose connection (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents).

Comment: And @MohammedSalah is totally right, this type of data does not belong in the params but in the headers. I managed to get a clean code working (https://github.com/SherloxFR/StackOverflow-Answers-Code/tree/master/multiple-mongo-databases), I'll be re-writing my answer.

Comment: @sherloxFR there will be one piece of each database that is different. I will need a way to insert data based on a user created form. That forms data will be structured differently based on the specific task at hand. It may just end up being an Object attached tot he relevant task though, i'm not 100% on implementation method yet. That need is the reason i am moving from SQL as i could not make a new table on the fly in mariaDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good way to do this would be to keep everything in the same database, and have a `hardware` field defined in each schema that is storing the hardware name from the request.

Then, on your endpoints, you would make Mongoose requests affecting only tasks where the hardware field is set to the hardware from the request.

Unless you have a very specific requirement that forces you to use multiple databases (which is surely not the case), that would be a misconception of your database schemas, even if it is probably doable (but will result in bad code imo).

[Code for my previous answer](https://github.com/SherloxFR/StackOverflow-Answers-Code/tree/master/answers/multiple-mongo-databases)

Comment: what i have now allows the end user to add a new piece of hardware without having to recode. They just go to hardwareC/tasks and when the database doesn't exist then it would be created and a template imported accordingly.. The concurrent instances thing as you have described is something i have seen in searching but it would not allow me to have the admin create a new instance on site.

Comment: Ultimatly what i want is for a user to be able to link to the hardware set relevant to themselves. since there is no log in for generic users it seemed that the best way to accomplish this was in params. Navigate to where you want then save a link, in the future click your link to go right there. If there is a better way then i am open to that too but that was my goal.

Comment: @Goofballtech who is the end user ?

Comment: @Goofballtech what is the platform used by the end user to comsume the API ? Webapp, cURL, other ?

Comment: @Goofballtech based on what you just told me, the good way to do this would be to keep everything in the same database, and have a `hardware` field defined in each schema that is storing the hardware name from the request. Then, ie on the getAllTasks endpoint, you would return every task where the `hardware` field is set to the hardware from the request. Unless you have a very specific requirement that forces you to use multiple databases, but I don't think that would be a good practice, even if it is probably doable (but will result in bad code imo)

Comment: @Goofballtech I'm going to bed, tell me if the solution I just proposed you suits your needs, so I can update my answer. If for any reason it doesn't, I'll come back to you tomorrow to try and figure out how to do this the right way.

Comment: @Goofballtech concerning your user generated form, this is definitively going to be stored as an object in your schema, you can still do some verification with the Javascript code (route file) that will insert it in your document, or with a Mongoose pre-save validation hook (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#order).

Comment: I think you got all the elements to your original + comments questions now, let me know if you have any other question. Could you please update your SO question with all those specifications so I can update my answer ? Thanks in advance and good night

Answer (score 1):

Accepted your answer because it gave enough detail for me to know i was going down, maybe not the wrong path, but one that was not easy for my current skill level. Ended up using the [mongo-tenant library](https://github.com/craftup/node-mongo-tenant) and now with the below i can filter much as you suggested within my single database. I can do user accesses later for read-only vs read-write and that should do anything i need as i don't need to segregate permissions by collection or anything like that.

Thanks very much for your help. 
Here is where i ended up.

api/index.js (unchanged from above)

api/routes/index.js (unchanged from above)

api/routes/taskRoute.js

```
const express = require('express')

const taskRoute = express.Router({ mergeParams: true })

const Task = require('../models/taskModel')

// get all tasks
taskRoute.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
  const boundTask = Task.byTenant(req.params.db)
  console.log(req.param.db)
  boundTask.find(function(err, tasks) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err)
    } else {
      res.json(tasks)
    }
  })
})

module.exports = taskRoute
```

api/models/taskModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongoTenant = require('mongo-tenant')

const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    taskID: {
      type: Number,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    taskName: String,
    category: String,
    lastCompletion: Date,
    detailDescription: Boolean,
    active: { type: Boolean, default: true }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)

taskSchema.plugin(mongoTenant)

const Task = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema)

module.exports = Task
```

then when i create a task or save it i add a property:
`tenantId: this.$route.param.db`
as defined in my vue project routes it'll pull the existing route so the task is created based on the currently open page.

this way hardwareA/tasks sorts out just the right stuff, one model set and one database.

Might run into an unforseen issue later but right now i think i can keep moving forward with data migration of existing stuff.

Thanks very much for you assistance in getting a working model. I won't be able to allow them to just create arbitrary databases this way but perhaps that's for the best anyway. I'll just framework some accepted generic terms for them to use in the even that's required.

Comment: Happy to know I helped, your solution is way better now ! Maybe the use of mongo-tenant is a little overkill as a simple Mongoose {hardware: req.params.db} would do the job, but if you are more comfortable with it then it's all good :)

Comment: it also give me room to grow, because it's running on a LAN anyway and will have 30 users and 10 tenant at the upper end the overhead for a library shouldn't make much difference. Thanks for taking the time.